# after update to 18.04, can't execute script file from terminal

Tags: updates

In ubuntu16.04, I was able to run a script file using ./filename.sh. but after update to ubuntu18.04, same file does not execute with "file not found" error. My system is 32 bit.

Comment: The `./filename.sh` includes a relative path (`./` is shorthand for the $PWD or present working directory) thus it maybe you are in a different directory to whatever directory you used to run it back when using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, thus the "*file not found*" error.  Use a full path instead of relative path.

Comment: The "un.sh" file is on desktop. I was using cmd from terminal "./Desktop/un.sh. now I am running terminal from desktop, and using the same command.

Comment: Also 18.04 update still shows Unity desktop in stead of  Gnome desktop.

Comment: I believe you can run it by `~/Desktop/un.sh`.

Comment: Unity is not the default desktop for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but is still available (including for later releases).  When you login you select which desktop you want to use, my own system has LXQt (Lubuntu), GNOME (Ubuntu), XFCE (Xubuntu) & MATE (Ubuntu-MATE) as choices; for the morning I was using GNOME, logged out hours ago now & switched to XFCE (Xubuntu). You can logout & likewise switch.   ~ is shorthand for your $HOME (/home/user/ directory) which is more precise than "./" which means relative to where you are when you run the command.` ~/Desktop/` is your `$HOME/Desktop` folder

Comment: prabhat@prabhat-ThinkCentre-xxx:~$ ./Desktop/un.sh        The o/p is     ./Desktop/un.sh: 11: ./Desktop/un.sh: linuxtechi@ubuntu-Rocks:~$: not found

Comment: In 16..04, I had no log in passward. 18.04, does not show log in page, and I have no option to choose desktop. it directly opens unity desktop and asks for key ring Password.

Comment: yes, I now see the button to choose Ubuntu(Gnome) and ubuntu on wayland, along with ubuntu default.    Also I notice that when I right click on desktop, there is  "new folder" option, and no "new" option for text document etc. Thanks.

Comment: I now made some script files and they are executing. the file before the update fails to execute. but this does my job. thank you.

Comment: I found my fault. There was an error in my old script. After correction, it is running. Thank You.